# Regular expression to replace a value with one from the same line

Tags: regex, visual-studio-code

I need to replace the word 'foo' with the value after the comma for each line - e.g. `'foo'` becomes `'bar1'`. The output should look likes this: `this.load.image('bar1', bar1);`

```
this.load.image('foo', bar1); 
this.load.image('foo', bar2); 
this.load.image('foo', bar3); 
...
```

How can this be done with a regular expression?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Search:**

```
\('[^']+',\s*([^\)]+)\);\s*$
```

**Replacement**

```
('$1', $1);
```

Depending on the text editor, it could be `\1` instead of `$1`. I use sublime, so I'm not sure which flavor vs code is using.

Explanation:

```
\(        - Match (
'[^']+',  - Match ', then all text until next ', next ' and the comma
\s*       - Zero or more spaces
([^\)]+)  - Capture group everything up to the next ). the group is important
\);\s*$   - Closing ); then any number of spaces and end of line.
```

Comment: Workes like a charm, thank you so much! Safes me a lot of copy pasting. :)

Comment: Yep, no problem. I do variants of this regex all the time for that exact reason.